# Does Wacaco really produce hot espresso (and how)?

Tags: espresso, equipment

Does anyone use [this](http://www.wacaco.com/) amazing apparatus?

I'm wondering if you can pour cold water in it and get a hot espresso (which, well, should be hot by definition)? If so, how does the heat come about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well according to the [video](https://youtu.be/lSppIjPSxyc?t=54s) presented on the website you have to provide hot water.

To my understanding of the machine's principle as well as physics there is absolutely no way it could produce hot coffee from cold water. The confusing quote from the FAQ

> Minipresso produces at ambient condition (75°F, 24°C), an espresso at perfect temperature (152°F, 67°C in cup) with a nice compact and persistent crema on top.

actually is about *temperature loss* during the process.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by temperature loss?

Comment: The water loses the temperature by heating its containers.

Comment: That makes sense, although one would expect some offset of that with the increased pressure.

Comment: We are talking about liquid, the pressure does not considerabely affect the temperature. Not as much as with gases.

Comment: True.  However, there is some gas being compressed in there as well, and that gas' increased temperature should transfer to the fluid and container as well.  It's probably just less than the heat lost to the device acting as a sink.

Comment: You are overthinking it :) the temperature change caused by pressuring the air does not really matter

Comment: Fair enough -- I didn't notice the videos!

Comment: Completely correct.  Received mine in the mail today.  Using boiling water produces a shot of espresso at a hot but very drinkable temperature.  I'd call it perfect, actually, as my own opinion (on the temperature).